# How to make the environment variable shared both by bash and python3 conveniently?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, environment-variables

I have written a environment variable in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

```
MY_PASS="xxxx"
```

Call the variable in bash is simple.

```
echo $MY_PASS
```

You can write `$MY_PASS` in your bash script.Now how can get it with python3's os module?

```
import os
os.environ['MY_PASS']
```

I got error info:

```
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'MY_PASS'
```

How to make the environment variable shared both by bash and python3 conveniently?
In order to call by bash and python3 conveniently,which file shall i write the environment variable into?

Comment: `export MY_PASS="xxxx"`; or exit-code-safe variant, if xxxx is command substitution: `MY_PASS="xxxx"; export MY_PASS`

Comment: How to call it with python3?

Comment: `os.environ['MY_PASS']` is correct. However, since it was not exported, it was not visible to python.

Comment: "I have written a environment variable in `/etc/bash.bashrc`." No, you haven't. You have written a variable. It enters the environment when you (as others already wrote) export them. This is exactly the process for them to enter the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export `MY_PASS` so that it's available in child processes:

```
export MY_PASS
```

or export it and set its value in one command:

```
export MY_PASS=xxx
```